# How do you connect to Snowflake from DBEAVER using SAML2.0 for sso

Tags: single-sign-on, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbeaver

Snowflake is configured for IDP/SAML 2.0 for SSO.  I am using DBEAVER to connect to snowflake.

I can connect with Snowflake authentication, so its not a driver configuration issue.

I don't see how to configure for Snowflake that is using single-sign-on.   On the Dbeaver connection settings I see a setting called "externalbrowser" but I don't see where i put in the URL for the SSO page with the host IDP for snowflake.

Answer (score 1):

If Snowflake is configured to use SSO already, then when you select externalbrowser, it'll prompt you to authenticate via a browser for SSO when you make your DBeaver connection.  You don't need to specify a URL for the SSO page in your connection.

Comment: OK, so its a problem with the browser not being fired to open the SSO login page.  My experience right now is that it just times out.  I will look at that closer.

Comment: I am not prompted with external browser.

On a fresh creation of a sf connector I am setting: 
HOST
DATABASE
ROLE
and AUTHENTICATOR to "externalbrowser"

When I try to connect it gives error
"JDBC driver internal error: missing user name for opening session."

I next edited the config and provided a USER, and now it times-out and I am real sure I have my host address correct. 

  Connect to xxxxxx.eu-west-1.snowflakecomputing.com:443 [xxxxxx.eu-west-1.snowflakecomputing.com/52.211.107.158, xxxxxx.eu-west-1.snowflakecomputing.com/34.251.72.221] failed: Connection timed out: connect

Comment: This works without issue for me, so not sure how to help you.  You may want to reach out to Snowflake Support to lend you a hand debugging your specifics.

Comment: Set your default browser as Chrome and also login to snowflake on Chrome before connecting with DBeaver.